# Cannot access a disposed object : DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, beginread

I'm using `TCPClient` to connect to device and get some data as a strings, then I'm trying to save data to DB and getting

> "Cannot access a disposed object" error."

Maybe problem is because I'm trying to save to DB from async callback function? 
Please take a look, here are two functions: first one gets network stream, already connected to the device and starts reading data, second one is callback:

```
private void ReadDataAsync(NetworkStream nwStream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            messageStream mStream = new messageStream(nwStream, buffer);

            if (nwStream.CanRead)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting async");
                nwStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
                    new AsyncCallback(OnReadEndAsync), mStream);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot read stream");
            }
        }

        private void OnReadEndAsync(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            String message = "";

            messageStream mStream = (messageStream)result.AsyncState;
            int incDataSize = mStream.nwStream.EndRead(result);

            message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mStream.buffer, 0, incDataSize);
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            events = ProcessMessage(message);
            if(events.Any())
                 _repo.saveEventsToDB(events);
            if (mStream.nwStream.CanRead)
            {
                mStream.nwStream.BeginRead(mStream.buffer, 0, mStream.buffer.Length,
                    new AsyncCallback(OnReadEndAsync), mStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: None of this code shows the actual problem, your repository (*sigh*) has closed the context

Comment: As written here, your method are not really "async". And your code is not usable as is. But yes, if they are called asynchronously and the _repo field is closed/disposed meanwhile, this is your error. My guess is you don't properly handle lifetime for your dbcontext.

Comment: find which line causes error. and write on here to get answer from ppl.

Comment: Dig around in here  `_repo.saveEventsToDB(events);` work out why you have closed and disposed the context (somwhere else), this will be your answer

Comment: Thing is, if I call _repo.saveEventsToDB(events) from another place of program, for example, like this:

[HttpPost("saveone")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> saveOne(Event newEvent)
        {
            var events = new List<Event>();
            events.Add(newEvent);
            await  _repo.saveEventsToDB(events);
            return Ok(events);
        }'


it works. So i think problem is because I call it from callback function.. Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Stop to access a disposed private field from a callback ? Stop to manage your connection with the same lifetime as the repository against good practices ?

Comment: @AFract could you please give an advice how to do it properly, or where to get an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution!

So problem was that I used DataContext dependancy, which was injected in the controller constructor - and it was disposed after HTTP request was completed.

So solution is to inject dependancy manually in the function itself, which needs access to the database:

1. Inject scope factory IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory in the controller constructor.
2. Add this to my function where I need access to DBcontext:

   using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
   {
     var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService();
     ...
   }